# Как передать IDependencyResolver в Атрибут

Tags: asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, ninject

Добрый день!

Может кто-то подсказать?

В ASP.NET WEB API проекте используется IoC-контейнер Ninject.

[Ссылка](http://sergeyakopov.com/fixing-fluentvalidation-quirks/) на пост автора.

**Вопрос:** Как передать в атрибут `[FluentValidationActionFilter(???)]` IDependencyResolver. Если возможно, то хотелось бы увидеть пример.

```
  public class FluentValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute  
  {
     private readonly IDependencyResolver _resolver;

     public FluentValidationActionFilter(IDependencyResolver resolver)
     {
          _resolver = resolver;
     }

     public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
     {
          var actionArguments = GetTheActionArguments(actionContext);

          if (actionArguments == null)
          {
              return;
          }

          foreach (var actionArgument in actionArguments)
          {
               if (actionArgument.Value == null)
               {
                   var actionArgumentDescriptor = GetActionArgumentDescriptor(actionContext, actionArgument.Key);

                   if (actionArgumentDescriptor.IsOptional)
                   {
                      continue;
                   }

                   var validator = GetValidatorForActionArgumentType(actionArgumentDescriptor.ParameterType);

                   if (validator == null)
                   {
                        continue;
                   }

                   actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

                        return;
               }
               else
               {
                    var validator = GetValidatorForActionArgument(actionArgument.Value);

                    if (validator == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var validationResult = validator.Validate(actionArgument.Value);

                   if (validationResult.IsValid)
                   {
                       continue;
                   }

                   WriteErrorsToModelState(validationResult, actionContext);

                  return;
              }
          }
      }

      private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetTheActionArguments(HttpActionContext actionContext)
      {
          return actionContext.ActionArguments
        .Select(argument => argument);
      }

      private static HttpParameterDescriptor GetActionArgumentDescriptor(HttpActionContext actionContext, string actionArgumentName)
      {
           return actionContext.ActionDescriptor
        .GetParameters()
        .SingleOrDefault(prm => prm.ParameterName == actionArgumentName);
      }

      private IValidator GetValidatorForActionArgument(object actionArgument)
      {
           var abstractValidatorType = typeof (IValidator<>);
           var validatorForType = abstractValidatorType.MakeGenericType(actionArgument.GetType());

           return _resolver.GetService(validatorForType) as IValidator;
      }

      private IValidator GetValidatorForActionArgumentType(Type actionArgument)
      {
           var abstractValidatorType = typeof(IValidator<>);
           var validatorForType = abstractValidatorType.MakeGenericType(actionArgument);

           return _resolver.GetService(validatorForType) as IValidator;
      }

      private static void WriteErrorsToModelState(ValidationResult validationResults, HttpActionContext actionContext)
      {
           foreach (var error in validationResults.Errors)
           {
               actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
           }
      }
 }
```

ВСЕМ огромное спасибо!

Comment: Вот [такое](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29916075/2523686) есть мнение.

Comment: Хотя, пардон, вы же пытаетесь инжектировать _Resolver_, а не _IDependency_. Впрочем, ответ с en-SO, на мой взгляд, всё-таки заслуживает прочтения (плюс в нём ссылка на статью и на другой ответ).